# Quake 3 Arena LAN between OS X and Windows

Tags: networking, quake-3

We're trying to have a LAN party, I'm on a El Capitan (10.11.3) Mac and my fellows are on PCs with Windows.

Now, when they host, there's nothing I see and I'm not able to connect with `\connect ip-address`. When I host they can even see me in the servers list, but still unable to connect.

Anyone managed to accomplish this? Should I edit my Network preferences in any particular way?

P.S.: there's no Firewall or anything on my Mac.

Comment: It should just work, but ensure that your MAC is not blocking or ignoring these ports: TCP Ports 27950, 27952, 27960, 27965; UDP Ports
27950, 27952, 27960, 27965

Comment: They seem to be free and not blocked either. Well, that's a shame. We've managed to play CS 1.6 though, no problem with that. Anyway, thanks for the input.